# JTable only String columns are transparent

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which is transparent only for String columns.
It looks like on this 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HhVd.png).

What is the problem? Is it possible to make any object columns transparent?

```
    table = new JTable(takeOrderWithTableController.getData(), new String[] { "Nazwa", "Trucizna?", "Na receptę?",
            "Kod kreskowy", "Data ważności", "Ostatni dzień sprzedaży", "Ilość" }) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 2:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 3:
                return Integer.class;
            case 4:
                return String.class;
            case 5:
                return String.class;
            case 6:
                return Integer.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    };
    };
    DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    defaultTableCellRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    defaultTableCellRenderer.setOpaque(false);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Constants.MAIN_WINDOW_MIN_WIDTH-100, 500));
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
    mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
    table.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some code? It's rather hard to figure out the problem without it.

Comment: Done. this is a code which is responsible for table.

Comment: What happens if you specify each type renderer, i.e. `table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);`

Comment: @SteveChaloner, your answer solved problem. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to add

```
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, defaultTableCellRenderer);
```

It seems like if you're trying to make your table transparent, you have to  set the renderer for every class you use.
@SteveChaloner - thanks!